# Custom ListView open another custom ListView

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to create app(workout plan) which use a lot of listView.
It means: When I click "Create Exercise" -> new name of exercise is created in listView. One ListView for every names of exercises. ( I have this ).
But when I click on every item of this listView I want to create new series for each item. But when I click "Create new series" in first item and when I click the same but in a second item it's created in one listView.

But I would like to save this to another listView for every item.
Is it possible? As I think at now, every item should have own listView.

Actually, my question is: Why are every series created in one ListView? 
Because the is one common activity for create series?

Could someone help me to find a solution for my case?

In this photo I show my idea.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No need to create a new list view for each and every item.I recommend you to create a table in your db and retrieve items on your need and populate the list view on item click of your list view.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But when I create a table i.e with 10 type of exercises, and each type has i.e 10 name, and each name has 10 series. This is what I would like to build. But how can I do this with a table?  For example I have a table, and in this table I can make (Table of types)ItemOnClick and it invokes to another table with names and another table invokes to listView?

Comment: create separate table for exercise,name,series then use joins to get desired results

Comment: How do you see this? It means I can write exercise, name, series and put this into one table? But how can I join some number of series? It should be in other particular list? Do you have some explanation because I can't figure out with this. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below links as a references to create Custom List view as you have mentioned in your question:

http://www.pcsalt.com/android/listview-using-baseadapter-android/
http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-baseadapter/

first, you have to create an activity in that activity create one custom listview and in your custom adapter- register click listener like "convertView.setOnClickListener(...){...} in getView(...) method.

In that click listener you have to open another activity and put some value you needed in putExtra(..) like startActivity(new Intent(getApplicatonContext(),AnotherActivity.class).putExtra("tag","value"));

And in second activity you have to get that value using getIntent().getStringExtra("tag");

After that create another custom listview based on that value..

Hope this help you

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I have Adapter etc. I can create series for every name but that series are created in only one listView. 
But I can't find this solution in your answer. You mentioned that I need to have Activity which create custom ListView for every item?

Comment: No there is no need to create activity for each and every item for example I have 500 items so it is not feasible to create 500 activities at all. You just need to create one activity and pass particular item's value in that activity and the listview will fill data according to that item's value so your work will finish withing 2-3 screens. You can also notify second activity's list view using notifyDatasetChanged();

Comment: you can also set that data coming from database according to item's value.

Comment: I have this notify. But I understand your answer like I have my code. I create series of every particular name but that series are saved in one listView. I don't want to use this because there is disorder. In your solution is included that I will have every particular item in another list? Sorry for my mind but I can't figure out in this.